# nice scroll - two finger scroll on mac

Tags: jquery, macos, scroll

I'm creating page with smooth scroll efect - plugin nice scroll http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/.

My client has mac (safari 6) and he is scrolling my page by putting two fingers on touchpad. In that case, page is very, very quick scrolling to the end of page.

Of course when we scroll using mouse wheel every thing is ok - page is scrolling smoothly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486141/check-if-user-is-scrolling-with-trackpad

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any question, but if You want to deactivate the plugin in Safari and you are able to use PHP, you could use this Function to deactivate the plugin, if a user uses Safari (6).

```
    <?php
function getBrowser()
{
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Opera';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
}   
    ?>
```

Use it like this:

```
 $ua=getBrowser();
    $yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
    print_r($yourbrowser);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-browser.php