# Parallax smooth scroll with trackpad too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling, trackpad

I've tried many js plug-ins. It works perfectly with a mouse wheel but scrolling is 'too fast' with my mac trackpad mouse. I think javascript can't detect if you are using a trackpad, right?

Last plug-ins I tried are simplr-smoothscroll and Mousewheel. Here is the example.

---

any suggestion please?

Comment: Try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16696129/2835243) with the Mousewheel plugin.

Comment: Thank you. I finally used skrollr. js and It works fine.